# Mathematical model for magic square

Tags: mathematical-modeling, magic-square

As I spent some time on magic squares, it seems like the magic squares can be formed only with a odd number of rows/columns? Is it that.? If so why? is there a mathematical model that explains magic square?

Comment: Google Albrecht Dürer, Melancholia

Comment: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath295.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that magic squares can only be formed with an odd number of rows and columns. For instance, consider
$$\begin{matrix} 7 & 12 & 1 & 14 \\ 2 & 13 & 8 & 11 \\ 16 & 3 & 10 & 5 \\ 9 & 6 & 15 & 4 \end{matrix}$$
There are more examples, together with some explanations, on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).

Comment: Thanks Clive.. (I was not able to upvote). But i am also trying to have a model that well describes the properties of a magic square.. will post once i am able to get it...